# Hibernate... how does one do database/SQL queries?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

I (think I) understand that Hibernate offers me access to a relational database essentially as if I had a class(es) that matched whatever view(s) I define of some tables.

How do I get the results of a specific query to be accessible via a class?  In particular, can I issue a complex SQL query, and process multiple results?

Do I lose any of the power of SQL by using Hibernate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I (think I) understand that Hibernate offers me access to a relational database essentially as if I had a class(es) that matched whatever view(s) I define of some tables.

Hibernate provides a framework allowing to map an object model to your database and an API to manipulate data through this object model.

> How do I get the results of a specific query to be accessible via a class? In particular, can I issue a complex SQL query, and process multiple results?

I'm not sure I understood the question but let's see. The Hibernate way would be to use [HQL (Hibernate Query Language) queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) and/or [`Criteria` queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) to perform queries **on the object model**.

But you can also use Native SQL (sacrificing portability) to return [entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13696), [multiple entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13763) or even [non-managed entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13904) (see also [Hibernate 3.2: Transformers for HQL and SQL](http://relation.to/2133.lace)).

> Do I lose any of the power of SQL by using Hibernate?

HQL and the Criteria API are quite powerful - and **portable** - and will generate the proper SQL for your backend. If required, you can still use native SQL queries as already mentioned. But in most cases, HQL and `Criteria` work well and should be preferred.

#### See also

- [14. HQL: The Hibernate Query Language](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)
- [15. Criteria Queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)
- [16. Native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

Answer (score 3):

> Hibernate3 allows you to specify handwritten SQL, including stored procedures, for all create, update, delete, and load operations.

```
 sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID, NAME, BIRTHDATE FROM CATS").list();
```

More at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html